# Pass error after catch on promises

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs2, axios

Hi I'm new so sorry if my question does not formulate properly.

I want to define a promise from axios js in a global function.
Here I want to handle / catch the 401 status globally and logout the user.
I do not want to handle it in every single query.

Here my source global function to handle a request:

```
export function requestData (url, payload = {}) {
  return axios.post(url, payload)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        logout()
      } else {
        return error
      }
    })
}
```

And here a example function I use on a controller:

```
requestData('/api/persons', {options: this.options, search: search})
  .then(data => {
    this.data = data
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.error = error.toString()
  })
```

My Problem is that the promise catch in my controller will not fire when there is an exception. How to realize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `return error` by `throw error` is the half work.
When I'm right the `throw error` in promise catch will not invoke the next promise .catch statement. This will work in the .then statement.

This way it should work:

```
export function requestData (url, payload = {}) {
  return axios.post(url, payload)
    .then(response => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        logout()
      } else {
        return error
      }
    })
   .then(result => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        throw result
      } else {
        return result
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

change `return error` in your `requestData` function to `throw error`

Comment: Thanks for help, but the error don't fire on my query promise catch. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

> You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by then or catch.

You're going to want to use the Response Interceptor:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
  // Do something with response data
  return response;
}, function(error) {
  // Do something with response error
  if (error.status === 401) {
    logout()
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```